# Is it valid to define a conditional probability in this way?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $(X,Y)$ be a pair of random variables taking their values from $\mathbb{R}^d, \{0,1\}$.for a Borel-measurable set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, 
\begin{eqnarray}
\mu(A) = \mathbf{P}\{X\in A\}
\end{eqnarray}
and for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$, $\eta(x)$ defined as 
\begin{eqnarray}
\eta(x) = \mathbf{P}(Y=y\vert X=x)
\end{eqnarray}
[see Devroye et al.](http://www.szit.bme.hu/~gyorfi/pbook.pdf) 
Then in page 15, it is said that " we have access to nonnegative function $\tilde{\eta}(x)$, $1-\tilde{\eta}(x)$ that approximate $\eta(x)$ and $1-\eta(x)$ respectively."

In my work, I want to define a function $\tilde{\eta}$ such that $\textit{given}$ $\mathcal{D}=\{(x_1, y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)\}$, it approximates $\eta(x)$. How should I define it so that I can use Bayes formulas for conditional probability?

I defined it as $\tilde{\eta}(x,y,  \mathcal{D})= p(Y=y\vert X=x, \mathcal{D})$, where by small $p$, I mean an estimate of the conditional probability using $D$ (data). But someone told me that it is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the risk with function $g(x)$ as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
L = P[g(x)\ne Y]
\end{eqnarray}
Then we have 
\begin{eqnarray}
L = \int_{R^d} P[g(x)\ne Y\vert X=x, D_n]\mu(dx)
\end{eqnarray}
where $D_n$ is data. 
Then 
\begin{eqnarray}
P[g(x)\ne Y\vert X=x, D_n] &&= 1-P[g(x) = Y\vert X=x, D_n]\cr
&&= 1- P[g(x)=1,  Y=1\vert X=x, D_n] -P[g(x)=0,  Y=0\vert X=x, D_n]\cr
&&= 1- I_{[g(x)=1]} P[Y=1\vert X=x, D_n] -I_{[g(x)=0]} P[Y=0\vert X=x, D_n]
\end{eqnarray}
So we can define 
\begin{eqnarray}
\bar{\eta}(x,y,D) = P[Y=1\vert X=x, D]
\end{eqnarray}